# resource for migrating from C/C++ to C#

Tags: c#, programming-languages

I know there's a lot of resource for this via google, but I just wanted to hear personally from people who have experienced this before. I've programmed in C for 3 years and C++ for a year and now I am moving to C#. I know this is not going to be a so hard transition but could you guys that had this same experience with me share resources on a good book, article, or blog to make my study experience more efficient. Any tips/tricks or gotchas when moving to C#?

Here's [one](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc301520.aspx) article that I can find via google. Looking for more goodies from experienced developers here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Richter's CLR Via C#](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735621632) book is the one that helped me to migrate.

Answer (score 3):

One piece of advice: don't try to use destructors in C# like you did in C++.

They look similar in both languages but they don't serve the same purpose. If you think you want a destructor in C#, you really probably want to implement [`IDisposable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.aspx).